# Can I safely hang a 27 kg boxing bag from a ceiling beam in my garage?

Tags: ceiling, garage, structural, beam, hanging

I want to hang a 27 kg boxing bag from a ceiling beam in my garage, but I'm concerned about the safety of doing so. The garage was built in the 60s, and the wood in the structure is quite old. I'm not sure if it will be able to support the weight of the bag, especially when factoring in the swinging motion.

I have calculated that the bag and the swinging motion will require the beam to support around 200 kg. I have attached a picture of the location where I want to hang the bag and the support structure itself.

[image]
[image]

I am also considering creating a type of pulley with a climbing rope that hangs over where the two triangular beams meet where I hang the bag at the end of the rope, as it seems like the strongest point.

My question is, is it safe to hang a 27 kg boxing bag from this ceiling beam in my garage? How can I determine if the beam is strong enough to support the weight and motion of the bag? Are there any additional supports or reinforcements I should consider adding to ensure safety?

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) You say "picture of the location" but the pictures are of almost the entire building.  If you have a specific place where you REALLY want it, please specify.  2) Are your rafter ties in two pieces, tied in the middle with nails?  If so I'd avoid putting heavy jiggly things near there.  3)   Can you hang the bag from or near the beam at the end?  Maybe run a board near there using two rafter ties and the beam for support and bracing?  Would that work for you? 4) What's with the floor above?  Was that in the engineering plan? What's kept on it?  That PLUS the bag ..... ??

Comment: There are no "rafter ties" here - those are clearly trusses. That also means there isn't a beam except at the sidewall between the columns, where hanging a bag would be impractical as it would be against the side-wall - there are only truss chords and truss webs for structure.

Comment: @jay613 also, the pics should ideally be a little more detailed than the current thumbnail size! :)

Comment: @Ecnerwal I stand corrected but am I correct in principle, IE that the chord is designed for certain forces, the splice in particular is designed for tension, and heavy side-to-side swinging could tear it apart?  If that's where OP wants to hang it, which we don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing in my previous house. The weight of the bag was not the issue. It was the swinging movement that caused damage. I had plaster ceiling that started cracking severly because of the movement of the truss.  I had to eventually remove the bag.

So I would advise some decent inter truss bracing.